# Why is my content not showing up in grids? (React.js)

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I am following [Hamza Mirza's React tutorial on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PbJt7-a2274) to build a movie search app, but I can't seem to have the movie results show up in a column / grids. (You'll notice that I'm using a different API here, for a different search-app purpose.)

My Movies component is as following:

```
import React from 'react';

// Don't need a state, so a stateless component!
// The "props" below is referring to "movies" in <Movies movies={this.state.movies}/> in App.js
const Movies = props => (
    <div className='container'>
        <div className='row'>
            {props.movies.map((movie) => {
            return (
                <div key={movie.id} className='col-md-4' style={{marginBottom:'2rem'}}>
                    <div className='recipes__box'>
                        <img 
                            src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${movie.poster_path}`} 
                            alt={movie.title}>
                        </img>
                        <div className='recipe__text'>
                            <h5 className='recipes__title'>{movie.title}</h5>
                            <p className='recipes__subtitle'>{movie.release_date}</p>
                            <p>Rating: {movie.vote_average}/10</p>
                        </div>
                        <button className='recipe_buttons'>Details</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
            } )} 
        </div>
    </div>
);

export default Movies;
```

It currently looks like this:
[image]

But I would like it to look like this (of course, with different content):
[image]

I cross-checked between my recipe app and this movie search app, and I'm not able to find any fundamental difference (other than the fact that they are using different APIs, of course). Is it that my Bootstrap / grid is not working? My package.json tells me that I successfully downloaded Bootstrap v.4.4.1, which is the version I used in my recipe app.

Anyway, let me know if I need to share other code within my React project. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

to index.js, could be helped if you've forgotten

Comment: Ah, it worked! That was the piece I was missing. Thanks so much, Alex!